# BetterLog duplicates output for each message to Google App Script console two times

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, logging

[BetterLog Apps Script library](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog) prints each message to `Google Apps Script console` two times.
Is it possible to configure it somehow or it is a bug?

I use standard configuration as recommended on [the library's page](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog):

```
// Add one line to use BetterLog
Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet('your-spreadsheet-key-goes-here'); 

//Now you can log and it will also log to the spreadsheet
Logger.log("That's all you need to do");
```

Example of console log with messages duplications:

```
11:23:10 AM Info 2022-06-13 11:23:10:821 +0300 001169 INFO doPost called
11:23:10 AM Info doPost called
11:23:11 AM Info 2022-06-13 11:23:11:289 +0300 001637 INFO doPost - contents: {"message":{"chat":{"id":123},"text":"/test"}}; runFromChatId: 123; text: /test
11:23:11 AM Info doPost - contents: {"message":{"chat":{"id":123},"text":"/test"}}; runFromChatId: 123; text: /test
11:23:11 AM Info 2022-06-13 11:23:11:599 +0300 001947 INFO doPost - not yet validated runFromChatId: 123
11:23:11 AM Info doPost - not yet validated runFromChatId: 123
11:23:11 AM Info 2022-06-13 11:23:11:893 +0300 002241 INFO doPost - authFailedAmount: 0
11:23:11 AM Info doPost - authFailedAmount: 0
...
```

[image: Screenshot with output to console]

Answer (score 1):

About 1 year ago there is no such problem: messages printed to console only one time. Since then something was changed in the library or in `App Script` engine.

Now this appears to be a bug.
I created corresponding issue for this library:
[BetterLog duplicates output for each message to console two times](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog/issues/28)

---

As work around you can do the following:

Initial configuration:

```
Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID);
Logger.console = undefined; //Do not print messages to console second time.
//To print to console Logger.nativeLogger_ destination will be used.
```

Usage:

```
Logger.log("This message will go to console only one time");
```

[Work around for issue "BetterLog duplicates output for each message to console two times"](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog/issues/28#issuecomment-1153724244)

This work around disables printing to `console` destination. Logger still will be printing to console by means of enabled by default `nativeLogger_` destination.

---

As the second work around you can leave `console` destination enabled and disable `BetterLog.nativeLogger_` destination. Message will still be printed only one time. But this solution will not print long timestamps for the messages to the console. This might be more handy.

To do this for now you can use `BetterLog` not as external library but copy it source to your project and to add small fix for this library by yourself. Later if the library is fixed there will be no need for that.

To use `BetterLog` locally you need to create new file for example with name "LocalBetterLog" and paste the code from [this file](https://github.com/peterherrmann/BetterLog/blob/master/Code.gs) there.

Apply the fix. Instead of:

```
  //default console logging (built in with Google Apps Script's View > Logs...)
  nativeLogger_.log(convertUsingDefaultPatternLayout_(msg, level));
```

Use:

```
//Anton Samokat fix: messages are printed to console twicely. 
//Added check for nativeLogger_ is not null and not undefined 
//in order to be able to set nativeLogger_ as null 
//and in such a way to skip printing messages to it.
if(nativeLogger_) { 
  //default console logging (built in with Google Apps Script's View > Logs...)
  nativeLogger_.log(convertUsingDefaultPatternLayout_(msg, level));
}
```

Then initiate and configure the logger in the following way:

```
//log config start
//Logger = BetterLog.useSpreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID); //Use BetterLog library when it is fixed
const Logger = useSpreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID); // For now use local BetterLog logger
//To call function from another file you need just to call
//it by name, no imports, no file names specification.
//Logger.console = undefined; //do not print messages to console
Logger.nativeLogger_ = undefined; //do not print messages to console second time
//Logger.sheet_ = undefined; //do not print messages to sheet (this particular set 
//can be placed in initTestsEnvironment() function for using it in local tests runs 
//in order to skip printing to the sheet for not spamming it during the tests)
//log config end
```

Usage as usual in all cases:

```
Logger.log("This message will go to console only one time");
```